# How to take the result.text from barcodescanner and use as an array

Tags: angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to take the result.text that is returned from Cordova Barcode Scanner and parse the data string to be used into an array, so I can populate input fields with-in a form.

Here is my example code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    $scope.scanMaterial = function() {
        $cordovaBarcodeScanner
            .scan()
            .then(function(result) {
                var myresult  = result.text;

                alert(myresult); 
            }, function(error) {
                console.log("An error has happened " + error);
            });
    };
}, false);
```

The BarCode data that I am getting:
W:966227, I:0253-0050-22, MFG:01/15, B:034, QTY:56, N:00034

I end result is to take this string of data and get it so I can populate the following variables:

```
var dataObj = {
            SessionId: SessionId,
            JobId: $stateParams.JobId,
            ManufactureDate: $scope.ManufactureDate,
            BatchCode: $scope.BatchCode,
            SKU: $scope.SKU,
            ManufactureOrigin: 'unknown',
            CreatedClient: $scope.CreatedClient,
            Latitude: $scope.lat,
            Longitude: $scope.long,
            Product: { Id : 1}
        };

        cfpLoadingBar.start();
            $http.post(baseUrl + 'Material/PostNewMaterial', dataObj)
                .success(function() {
                    alertsManager.addAlert('Success: You have successfully added material.', 'alert-success');
                    cfpLoadingBar.complete();
                    $scope.materialCollapsed = true;
                }).error(function(dataObj) {
                    alertsManager.addAlert('Failure Meesage: ' + JSON.stringify({dataObj:dataObj}), 'alert-danger');
                    cfpLoadingBar.complete();
                });
                $timeout(function(){
                    alertsManager.clearAlerts();
                }, 5000);
    };
```

Comment: What's the issue or question you have?

Comment: I need to get the result.text to be used in a $http.post method for rest API. I am getting the results within an alert, but I am not sure how to use that for my intent. I need to some how PARSE the data into an array I would assume, so I can use $scope objects.

Comment: Sorry, but your comment makes little sense to me. Why can't you just use `result.text` in `$http.post` calls? Why do you think you need to *parse* data, and why would you need an array? You should probably extend the code in your question to a full but minimal repro, show us what you're currently trying to do. Including some fake data / injecting a fake `$cordovaBarcodeScanner` to illustrate your problem would also help.

Comment: Remember: we don't share your context. Your post is *all* we have to go on. Without context, your post is quite low on details.

Comment: The barcode data is: w: 966227, I:0253-0050-22, MFG:01/15, B:034, QTY: 56, N:00034.

Comment: You can edit your question to improve it / add details. If substantial, this will also bump the post. Make sure to use the live preview (and formatting help) to get the entire thing in shape before posting an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives the desired results, and splits the result.text into a usable format, that can then be sent back to the API server.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    $scope.scanMaterial = function() {


        $cordovaBarcodeScanner
            .scan()
            .then(function(result) {

                var codeArray = result.text.split(',');
                $scope.SKU = codeArray[1].replace("I:", "").trim();
                $scope.controlNo = codeArray[0].replace("W:", "").trim();
                $scope.ManufactureDate = codeArray[2].replace("MFG:", "").trim();
                $scope.BatchCode = codeArray[3].replace("B:", "").trim();

                var dataObj = {
                    SessionId: SessionId,
                    JobId: $stateParams.JobId,
                    ManufactureDate: $scope.ManufactureDate,
                    BatchCode: $scope.BatchCode,
                    SKU: $scope.SKU,
                    ManufactureOrigin: 'unknown',
                    CreatedClient: new Date(),
                    Latitude: $scope.lat,
                    Longitude: $scope.long,
                    Product: { Id : 1}
                };

                $http.post(baseUrl + 'Material/PostNewMaterial', dataObj)
                    .success(function() {
                        alertsManager.addAlert('Success: You have successfully added material.', 'alert-success');
                        $state.go('^');
                    }).error(function(dataObj) {
                        alertsManager.addAlert('Failure Meesage: ' + JSON.stringify({dataObj:dataObj}), 'alert-danger');
                    });
                    $timeout(function(){
                        alertsManager.clearAlerts();
                    }, 5000);

            }, function(error) {
                console.log("An error has happened " + error);
            });
    };
}, false);
```